# Checking if a DateTime is before DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datetime, if-statement, windows-phone-8

How can I check using some form of `if` statement if a certain `DateTime`, (say in this case called dateAndTime1) is before the current date and time, which I presume will be retrieved using `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx .. is one way.  As others have already pointed out, the usual comparison operators work too.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
if(dateAndTime1 < DateTime.Now)
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 7):

the <, <=, >, >= and == operators work on DateTime instances, so

`if(dateAndTime1 < DateTime.Now)`

Note that if you are comparing this in a loop, some small efficiency can be gained by setting `DateTime now = DateTime.Now` before the loop and comparing against `now`

Comment: per your note: you're right except on the edge case where it's a long running process and `now` always needs to be the immediate `DateTime.Now`. This is because when setting a `now` variable, it will be stale in long running processes... like I said though, "edge case", and probably rarely experienced.

Comment: Actually specifically because of that I'd rather use a variable that is consistent throughout the loop. Obviously it depends on the use case, but I can imagine that when returning a certain set of values to the user, the anchor point should almost always be constant for a consistent result.

Answer (score 2):

Inline works too.

```
// bool variable
bool isHistory = dateAndTime1 < DateTime.Now;

// string return statement
return dateAndTime1 < DateTime.Now ? "History" : "Future";
```

Comment: Just for everyone's benefit, the name for the expression used in your example is a ternary expression.